# How to stop the forces acting on a body in box2d

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, physics-engine

I am using box2d on the iphone to create a game. I have a body that is effected by gravity to move down and not right or left. It will get hit by another body and will then be moving right or left. I then have a reset button which moves the body back to its starting point. The only problem is that it is still moving right or left. How can I counteract the forces that a ball is already traveling? How can I get rid of this right and left movement when I reset my game?

Answer (score 27):

Box2d automatically clears the forces each simulation step. I think you are just changing your body's position when resetting, but not its velocity. Add this code to your reset method:

```
body->SetLinearVelocity(b2Vec2(0,0));
body->SetAngularVelocity(0);
```

Comment: I've tried this way but doesn't work when two object close to each other http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39716111/cocos2dx-unable-to-set-velocity-0-0

Comment: @TomSawyer: they probably collide after you reset the velocities and that causes their velocity to change again

Comment: I think resetting the velocity make one object stand still. it's impossible to collide to the other. Anyway to make sure one object has been stopped?